# Solving $ax \equiv b \pmod y$ where $a, b, y$ are known, $b \mid a$, and $y$ prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I want to find $x$ satisfying $ax \equiv b \pmod y$, provided that:

1. $a,y,b$ are known numbers
2. $b \mid a$
3. $y$ is not prime.

Comment: Do you by any chance mean $a \mid b$ for 2.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all people usually write $ax\equiv b \pmod{y}$ (i.e., no need to repeat the "$\pmod{y}$" in both sides).

Consider $d$ to be the gcd of $a$ and $y$. Then we have that since $ax-b=yc$ then since $d$ divides $y$ and $a$, the first thing you need to check is that the gcd of $y$ and $a$ divides $b$ (otherwise you wont have a solution).

Assuming that $d$ does divide $b$, then you can write: $(a/d)x-(b/d)=(y/d)c$ which implies that $(a/d)x\equiv  b/d\pmod{y/d}$. Since now by construction you have that $(a/d)$ is coprime to $y/d$, then $(a/d)$ is a unit in $\mathbb{Z}/(y/d)$, so you can find its inverse and multiply both sides by it to obtain: $x\equiv (a/d)^{-1} (b/d)\pmod{y/d}$ and further more you know the solution is unique up to a multiple of $y/d$.

Answer (score 1):

You can't always do it. For example, $6x \equiv 3 \operatorname{mod} 12$ satisfies $b \mid a$ and $y$ not prime but has no solutions. To see this, note that $6x \operatorname{mod} 12$, can only be $0$ or $6$.